# Mesos: what are the OS level techniques for resources allocation?

Tags: mesos

I understand Mesos architecture at a high level, but I'm not clear about the OS level techniques used to implement resources allocation. For example, Mesos offers a framework 1 CPU and 400MB memory, and another framework 2 CPUs and 1GB memory, how is this actually implemented at OS level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Mesos itself doesn't "allocate" any resources at the OS-level. The resources are still allocated by the OS, although Mesos can use OS-level primitives like cgroups to ensure that a task doesn't use more resources than it should.

1. The Mesos agent at the node advertises that some resources are available at the host (e.g., 4 CPUs and 16GB of RAM) -- either by auto-detecting what is available at the host or because the available resources have been explicitly configured (recommended for production).
2. The master then offers those resources to a framework.
3. The framework can then launch a task, using some or all of the resources available at the agent: e.g., the framework might launch a task with 2 CPUs and 8GB of RAM.
4. The agent then launches an executor to run the task.

   - How strictly the "2 CPUs and 8GB of RAM" resource limit is enforced depends on how Mesos is configured. For example, if the agent host supports cgroups and the agent is started with `--isolation='cgroups/cpu,cgroups/mem'`, cgroups will be used to throttle the CPU appropriately, and to kill the task if it tries to exceed its memory allocation.